# Is there a Windowlicker for wxpython?

Tags: junit, wxpython, pygtk, rpa, gui-testing

Having recently read "Growing OO systems guided by tests", I am very impressed with the [windowlicker](http://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/) testing utility for java/junit. Basically it wraps the GUI and GUI-interaction with drivers and gestures, so your integration/end-to-end tests can be written neatly like:

```
//setup
ui.enterUserDetailsFor(newUser)
ui.sendForm()
//assert
ui.showsWelcomeMessage()
```

All swing-gui-thread synchronization and finding widgets etc is nicely isolated in the framework. Exactly this sort of higher level testing is something I really miss in my current wxPython project. Is there anything at all similar for wxgtk/wxpython? 
What I can tell from the windowlicker source it builds on [java.awt.robot](http://www.science.uva.nl/ict/ossdocs/java/jdk1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), if there isn't a windowlicker, is there anything like robot?

Comment: The only real Windowlicker available is Aphex Twin's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of anything specifically for wxPython. You can use the Widget Inspection Tool for some of the stuff you are talking about though. See here:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool

There's also the Sikuli project which is GUI-agnostic:

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/

Hopefully one of those will help you out.

Comment: Nice! I'll have to troll around in that inpsection tool's source, maybe there's a python windowlicker in the making there! :) Meanwhile, sikuli was really cool